# how to disable dates after one year from today in android studio

Tags: java, android

> im working with material date range picker in android studio
>
> i want the way to disable future date after (360 - 7) days from today--for example
>
> today is 3/11/2022 i want to disable future date start from 28/10/2023
>
> how can i do that???

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> materialDatePicker=MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
        MaterialDatePicker builder=materialDatePicker.build();

        CalendarConstraints.Builder calendarConstraints=new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
        RangeDateBuilder rangeDateBuilder=new RangeDateBuilder(353);
        
        materialDatePicker.setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraints.build());
        calendarConstraints.setValidator(rangeDateBuilder);
        rangeDateBuilder.setDatePicker(builder);
        btnFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                builder.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Date_Picker");
            }
        });

    @SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
    public class RangeDateBuilder implements CalendarConstraints.DateValidator{
        int numberOfDays;
        MaterialDatePicker rangepicker;

        public RangeDateBuilder(int numberOfDays){
            this.numberOfDays=numberOfDays;
        }

        public void setDatePicker(MaterialDatePicker rangepicker){
         this.rangepicker=rangepicker;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(long date) {
            Pair<Long, Long> selection =(Pair<Long, Long>) rangepicker . getSelection ();
            if (selection != null) {
                Long startDate = selection . first;
                if (startDate != null) {
                    long days =(numberOfDays - 1) * TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);;
                    if (date > startDate + days)
                        return false;
                    if (date < startDate)
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

        }


    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use setMinDate() and setMaxDate() on the DatePicker. You can access it from your DatePickerDialog with getDatePicker().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html